# ¿Lo que se piensa/cree que te van a decir tiene que ir obligatoriamente con comillas y dos puntos?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, puntuación, redacción

Transcribiendo un poco me encontré con algo semejante a lo siguiente:

> Yo hablaba muy entretenido con ella. Pero sin meditarlo le dije algo un poco indebido. Pensé que me iba decir: **«Metido»**. Dije: «Pero te ves tan linda y no te maquillas. Natural». Y me dijo: «Porque yo decidí que esa era mi diferencia».

Mi pregunta es referente a ese «metido», ¿tendría que ser introducido de esa forma? ¿O tiene que ir sin dos puntos y sin comillas?

Aunque siento que se trata de discurso directo, no estoy muy seguro porque mi caso abarca lo que se piensa (o se cree) que se va a decir, y no lo que te dicen (o dijeron). Así que me parece que tiene que ir sin estas marcas:

> Yo hablaba muy entretenido con ella. Pero sin meditarlo le dije algo un poco indebido. Pensé que me iba decir **metido**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera en la que lo escribiste es una de las posibles, entre otras, con lo cual no significa que haya una forma obligatoria. El objetivo siempre es presentarlos de manera coprensible.

Una forma clásica en la que el diálogo se expresa en los textos recurre al uso de la raya larga ("**—**" , **em-dash** en ingles, símbolo que en Windows se introduce presionando "Alt + 0151")

En los diálogos dicho símbolo sirve para diferenciar el componente de

- el **parlamento** (lo que alguien dice), de
- la **acotación** (que es el inciso hecho por el narrador)

Más detalles sobre las particularidades de presentarlos como intercambios literales, puede leerse [en este documento producido por la RAE](https://www.rae.es/dpd/raya)

Para el ejemplo tuyo, una adaptación a ese formato posible sería:

> Yo hablaba muy entretenido con ella, pero sin meditarlo le dije algo un poco indebido. (Pensé que me iba a decir «Metido»)
> —Pero te ves tan linda y no te maquillas. Natural —le dije
> —Porque yo decidí que esa era mi diferencia —contestó

Comment: Pero con las comillas ortotipográficas, es decir:

_(Pensé que me iba a decir «Metido»)._

Comment: Cierto. Ahi lo cambié. (leí que la RAE recomienda siempre usar las comillas latinas, antes que las dobles y las simples, con esa prioridad http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KGNHTWJboACCgatE)

Comment: No lo había pensado. Pero tienes razón. La secuencia de mi duda podría ser considerado por entero un inciso. Por tanto, incluirlo entre paréntesis (como has hecho) sería también correcto. En ese caso que mencionas no se tienen que colocar los dos puntos, pero sí la palabra entre comillas y con mayúscula inicial. ¿Cierto?

Comment: Entiendo que si. Para el uno de las mayúsculas si hay unas reglas más estrictas —que puedes consultarlas en https://www.rae.es/dpd/mayúsculas— por ejemplo allí está la justificación de tu uso inicial (correcto) de mayúsgulas tras los dos puntos y la abertura de comillas